# find the slope and the y-intercept

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with the steps of finding the slope and $y$-intercept of this equation: $f(x)=3x-\frac{1}{5}$. I am in Algebra two and do not understand the proper ways, or steps of doing this.

Comment: You want to be aware of the slope's appearance in the slope-intercept form $y=f(x)=mx+b$. But you also may want to be aware of the definition of slope as rise over run, or change in $y$ over change in $x$. Similarly, for the $y$-intercept, consider two facts regarding these. One, that the line will intercept the $y$-axis when $x=0$ (convince yourself of that geometrically), and the appearance of the $y$-intercept in $y=mx+b$. Try to locate these concepts in your textbook.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The equation $\;y = mx + b\;$ is an equation of a line in **slope-intercept form**: $$\large y = \underbrace{m}_{\text{slope}}x + \underbrace{b}_{\text{y-intercept}}\tag{ slope-intercept form}$$

So, in your case $$y = \underbrace{{\bf 3}}_{\bf m} x + \underbrace{\bf \left(-\frac 15\right)}_{\bf b}$$

Comment: nice use of brackets again +1

Answer (score 1):

In the equation $f(x)=m x+c$ the slope is given by $m$ and the y-intercept by $c$. This is because the slope is how much the function increases by each time we increase $x$ by one (try this for any two values of $x$ that are one apart) and the y-intercept is the value of $f(x)$ when $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Slope of a function $f$ at any point $(a,f(a))$ is given by $\frac{d(f(x))}{dx}|_{x=a}$ and $y-$intercept is given by $f(0)$

Comment: OP is in Algebra II, not Calculus

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Do you recognize the equation $y=mx+b$? If so, what are the $m$ and $b$?